# DataGrid filter by date

Tags: c#, winforms, date, datagrid

So once again, im stuck with an issue, i have never used DataGrids in great detail before, so this is probably where the issue is.

My problem is i have a datagrid one of the columns is Date, each row has a date which is a string formatted like so.

30/06/1995

i have two text boxes on my form one being a start date another being an end date, what i would like is the Datagrid to only show the Rows/Records the Dates in between Start and End.When the user enters the dates and apply the filter (i have button that applys all my filters this is my last filter im struggling with)

In sudo code terms i understand what needs to be done, but when it comes to C# i dont have a clue.

So far im using something like this.

//DATE AND TIME FILTERING

```
        if (rangeCheckBox.Checked)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(col.HeaderText);
            }
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                DataRow dRow = dt.NewRow();
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    dRow[cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dRow);
            }
            DataView dv = new DataView(dt);

            dv.RowFilter = "(Date >= #" +                           Convert.ToDateTime(startDate.Text).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "# And Date <= #" + Convert.ToDateTime(endDate.Text).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "# )";
```

//The above would not format properly on here dont know why

```
            var source = new BindingSource();

            source.DataSource = dv;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
```

This code does not seem to do anything, i have searched for hours today with not much luck, i also did post this earlier, but had no luck.

Many Thanks

EDIT:::

public class ImagesInfo
    {

```
    public string FileName { get; set; } 
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FileName;//Used for the Selection of Picture combo box

    }



    The records come from a formatted text doc they are then put into this list

     public static List<ImagesInfo> images = new List<ImagesInfo>();
```

Comment: To which the `DataGridView` is data bound? Why you generate `DataTable` to filter the grid in that ugly manner?

Comment: The DataGrid is bound to a list of records, the reason it is then transferred into a datatable is because it is then put into a Data View and i try to filter it, but it i did not work, so i am now here.

Comment: `list of records` What type of the `record. Show definition.

Comment: Edited my post including what you asked

Comment: You have serious problem in your model. Why `Date` is string? You must change its type to avoid a bunch of problems.

Comment: The reason Date is set to String is because when the document is saved  it saves from the Datagrid, when i used to have it as DateTime Date; its used write a null time after like 00:00:00 which rendered it useless to me as i could not read it back into my program the way i wanted. Is there not way i can just convert that column to DateTime when i want to do the Filtering? As that is all the date is used for in my app.

Comment: Did you hear about Nullable types?

Comment: I have just read up about them, the basics is that different values can be assigned at different times? Hows does that apply if you dont mind me asking?

Comment: Did you read this? [Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) `Nullable types are instances of the System.Nullable<T> struct. A nullable type can represent the correct range of values for its underlying value type, plus an additional null value.`